# Separate 1 column data to 2 column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following data in my sql table:

```
 Tran_Date          |  Amount 
2013-05-01 20:09:49 |  50.00
2013-05-02 04:09:49 |  50.00
2013-05-02 04:30:49 |  10.00
2013-05-02 20:09:49 | 500.00
2013-05-03 03:09:49 |   0.00
```

How to separate the amount to today and next day before 5am? The result should as below.The purpose to get the result is because the shop open at 8am and close on next day 5am. I have to calculate the sum before 8am-12am,sum after 12am-5am to make it as 1 day sales.

```
    Tran_Date       |  Amount |  Amount_Before_5am
2013-05-01 20:09:49 |  50.00  |       60.00
2013-05-02 20:09:49 |  500.00 |        0.00
```

Hope you all can help me. I was trying the following code almost 1 week but get nothing. Is it possible to do that? Thanks

```
select CAST(DATEADD(hh, -5,c.TRAN_DATE) AS DATE),
       CAST(c.TRAN_DATE as DATE),
       sum(c.Amount)
from TRAN_TABLE 
group by CAST(DATEADD(hh, -5,c.TRAN_DATE) AS DATE),
         CAST(c.TRAN_DATE as DATE)
```

Comment: Can you please spell out the logic you used to get this result?  Also indicate what `today` means in your case.

Comment: What if there's an amount before 5 AM, but no corresponding amount the previous day? What if there are multiple records either before or after 5 AM?

Comment: The purpose to get the result is because the shop open at 8am and close on next day 5am. I have to calculate the sum before 8am-12am,sum after 12am-5am to make it as 1 day sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to do this efficently.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/615d5/2

```
SELECT BusinessDay = CAST(DATEADD(hh,-5,TranDate) AS DATE)
      ,Amount = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,TranDate) >  4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
      ,Amount_Before_5am = 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,TranDate) <= 4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hh,-5,TranDate) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is working perfect. Thank you very much and appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with aggregation, another approach is using `join`:

```
select tt.trandate, tt.amount, ttnext.amount
from Tran_table tt left outer join
     Tran_Table ttnext
     on hour(ttnext.tran_date) < 5 and
        cast(ttnext.tran_date as DATE) = CAST(tt.tran_date + 1 as DATE)
where hour(tt.tran_date) >= 5;
```

This assumes that the data conforms to your description in the question.  Multiple values before 5 a.m. or after 5:00 a.m. on the same day would cause duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    Tran_Date
    , Amount
    , Amount_Before_5am = SUM(CASE WHEN CAST('Tran_Date' AS TIME) <'05:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
FROM TRAN_TABLE 
GROUP BY Tran_Date, Amount
```

Hard to tell from your question if you're aggregating or not.  If you are, then this should work. If you're not aggregating, then just take the SUM() off.  You can also use DATEPART comparison as others noted.

Oh, you probably wanted Amount Summed by day too?  Just wrap that in SUM() and remove Amount from the Group By clause.